# Make Apache server virtual host to point to internal IP

Tags: node.js, dns, apache2

I'm beginner at Linux and Apache so this may be a trivial question for pros. Even though I was looking for a way to make virtual host to point to an internal IP address in Ubuntu like this:

You will be connecting Socket.io to node.domain.com -> virtual host -> localhost:3000

Why can't I just do this? domain.com:3000
Because at some schools and public places may be blocked most of ports except 80 and 443.

PS. I can't buy another server just for Node.js where I could edit A-Records.

Thank you so much in advance for all answers and suggestions.

Comment: Maybe you could post this question on the ServerFault or Unix&Linux community as this question does not really imply some code but is rather configuring Apache and your server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to look at Apache's mod_proxy https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html